# これなんでマイナスなんですか

Tags: 討議

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23668/%E4%B8%80%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E9%A0%BB%E7%B9%81%E3%81%ABfopen%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E8%89%AF%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84?noredirect=1#comment22603_23668

以下のようなコメントをもらいました

> 1 
>          Linux なら mmap(),, Windows なら MapViewOfFile() とかでいかがでしょうか。 – masm 15時間前

これは初めて知ったのでそのままの文面です

> 1 プラス投票済み位置づけにはfseek等を使用するようにしてみてはどうでしょうか？。また、atoi(fgetc(fp))は間違いのように思います。 –
>   BLUEPIXY 15時間前

このひとコメントで毎回承認されるレベルの回答書いてきます。
なので皮肉って返信書きました
（たまにまと外すこともあるけど）

> 3数十万桁くらいなら、一桁あたり1バイトで 1MB にもならないので、楽にメモリに収まります。 – Hideki 14時間前

こういう回答出てくると思っていました。
で桁数を多めにとってたんですけど計算めんどうだったので数十万で書いておきました。
もちろんこれにもソースがあって
http://www1.cts.ne.jp/~clab/hsample/IO/IO19.html
ここのイントが参考になってる６万程度じゃなかったかなぁと思ってたから１０万ね
このイントに従えば一次元配列でエラー
経験なければ普通にかける回答だなって
mallocで確保しても引数がintだったら配列よりも1/sizeof(int)分小さくなるじゃん純粋な各補の仕方じゃ上手にできないよね
C++なら気にせずstd::vector使えばCのそれよりも多く確保できるんだよねそれ回避のためにCのタグしか入れてない。
だから、メモリについて本気で答えるなら一番上のコメントしかないんですよ
こんな回答ばっかり評価されて

> 1 プラス投票済み fp を先頭に戻すなら rewind() があります。 – masm 13時間前

これも素直に書きました。知らなかったのですから。

> 2 
>          「数十万桁」（数100KB）と「13.3兆」（13TB）とでは要件が明らかに異なります。「桁数はあくまで参考値です」などと質問内容を曖昧にしないでください。
>   – sayuri 1時間前

ファイルのサイズは変わりましたが？どちらもパイですが？プログラムに求める要件はファイルサイズが基準ですか？パイが基準ですか？
私はパイを基準にしました
コードにツッコミ入れてくれるのを期待しましたがなんか変なの帰ってきてるのでがっかりです。

まぁ。確かに時間を基準にするアルゴリズムとメモリを基準にするアルゴリズムこのどちらを求めているかまでは正しく書いてない
経験がない人から回答を得ると多くの時間と労力を消費する。ファイルを変えたら確実にもう一度ここで質問していたと思うよ。それはポイントのない人にとっては好都合だろうけど
mallocで通用しなくなるまで、書いてメモリに保存するのはやめましょうなんて言われたら、設計に根本的な問題があった場合、大抵ここクローズでしょ？
そんな運びされたらできるものもできないで終わってしまう
それは問題がない？

Answer (score 12):

内容というよりフォーマットの問題かと思います。

恐らくtodoさんが抱えている問題は一つの質問に収まらない物なのだと思います。
抱えている問題セットを一つの質問にしてしまうと、そのままでは同じ問題セットを抱えている人にしか役立たない問答になってしまいます。
賛否あるでしょうが、StackOverflowでは面倒でも個別の質問にするべきだと思います。

質問を分解するとこんな感じでしょうか。

- 一つのファイルを頻繁にfopenするのは良くない事か
- 開こうとしたファイルが開けなかった時のリスクと対処方法
- 一度にメモリに読み込めないほど大きいファイルを一部分ずつ処理するよい方法
- fpを先頭に戻す方法はあるか
- 動的に確保したメモリ領域の制約
- このコードのfseekの使い方は正しいか

その他に、

- 「円周率数十万桁」といった場合に想定が必要なデータサイズは「数十万桁」ではなく「円周率の長さ、つまりは無限」である

という主張をはじめとして、コメントに対する感想・意見が混じっています。
これを書きたい気持は分かりますし、どうするのが良いのか分かりません。
しかし、やはり質問に追記していくのは StackOverflow 的には違うでしょう。

Comment: 前提を質問にしないでくださいよ（笑
前提、因果関係を断つ部分が甘かったのはありますけど、プログラム内部で直接πを求めないでファイルでいくらでもバリアブルなものだと考えていなかったのは、特定ページの専用ブラウザを作る時代にはそぐわない概念だったかもしれませんね。

Comment: @todo さんはその「前提」についても自信がなくて、質問調で書いています。ですから少し極端に別個の質問として抜き出しました。私は一問一答形式に収斂する傾向があるStackOverflowが好きなので。自分の取り組んでいる問題について長々と書いてあったり、議論を始めているような質問を見ると「ブログかよ」と思ってしまいます。@Yuki Inoue さんは「本当にやりたい事」を記せと書いていますが、自分はむしろ逆の感想です。「円周率」とか「数十万桁」とかはいらなくて、「一度にメモリに読み込めないほど大きいファイルを一部分ずつ処理するよい方法」のみ質問するのがよい質問だと感じます。まあ好みかもしれない。あれほどマイナス票が入ったのは仕様変更に対するプログラマの拒否反応ですから、深く考える必要はないです。

Comment: 自信ありまくりだったら動くからこれでいいって質問にすらならなかったかもしれませんね。「ブログかよ」については３つの視点があったかと開発者のブログから、追記についても過去の議論で上がってたりします。あと、具体例を示せないとって経験がありましたので抽象的に聞けなかったのです。

Comment: 経緯を考えれば todo さんが`seek`系関数に辿り着くために必要なプロセスだったかもしれません。それで、結果として長々とした質問が残ってしまったと。まあ、仕方ないですね。

Answer (score 10):

私自身は投票はしてないのですが、質問とこのメタの質問を読んでも何を言っているのか理解できない文章が多くマイナス票入れられても仕方ないかなと思います。句読点がないとかくだけた口語調などの文法的な問題、技術的に意味不明、主題がない(単なるおしゃべり)、などが入り交じっているのが原因です。

もう一つ大きいのは「数十万桁」という当初の要件を「13兆桁を考慮しろ」と後出しで変更したうえ、当初の要件を元にした回答を揶揄するような返信を書かれたことです。こういうことをやられると質問回答のやりとりが成立しないしする気が無いと思われても仕方が無いです。一般論として人にものを尋ねる態度ではないですね。

---

SOはおしゃべりをする場ではありません。それはさておくとしても、おしゃべりがしたいならなおさら他人に理解してもらえるような文章を書く努力と礼儀が必要でしょう。

Comment: 単なるおしゃべりは仕方ないです。それを話せる人、理解できるが人Q&Aのサイトにしかいないからです。「１３兆桁」なんて現実味無いと思いませんか？

Answer (score 2):

[XY 問題](http://xyproblem.info) という話があります。本当に何をやりたいのか？という話についてです。

サイズ無限大のファイルなんてものは、有限情報しか保持できないPCで取り扱うことができないため、必ずどこかで妥協する必要があります。

この原則を踏まえた上で、今 @todo さんが本当に何の問題を解こうとしているのか？がわからないために、ファイルサイズ・メモリの話が出てきているのだと思います。

(メモリに乗っかるサイズ・ファイルシステムに保管できるサイズ・大容量データベースで管理するしかないサイズ、取り扱いたいサイズで書くべきプログラムは変わってきます)

- 例1: メモリに乗っかる程度 -> メモリに乗っければいい。
- 例2: ファイルシステムには保管できる程度 -> 今回の todo さんの想定？
- 例3: 大容量データベース -> どうするんでしょうね、自分もよく知らないです。
- 例4: 無限大 pi データ -> 計算機では無理なので、数学的にどうこうするしかないかと。。

Comment: 本当にやりたいかじゃなくて前提にある問題をすっ飛ばすってことじゃないの？

Comment: 前提(根本)にある問題をすっ飛ばした問題提起をしていたら、それをxy 問題と呼びます、ということですね

Comment: 状態としては完全にフィットしてるけど、なんか、ちょっとだけ違う気がした。たしかに、解決策としてメモリに収めることは除外する予定で聞いた。ただ、数値が甘かった。数値を大きすぎるものにするとここでは本当に解きたいのか聞かれるから。

Comment: サイズをたとえば TB とか PB とか(もしくはそれ以上)にした場合には、「本当にそれを解きたいのか？(解くべき問題なのか？)」というコメント(ないしクローズ票)よりは、「本が書けるぐらいに広範な問題だから、Q&A サイトである stackoverflow では扱えません」 というコメント(ないしクローズ票) が飛んでくるとは思ってます。